# Is it possible? Combine all JavaScript into one file

Tags: javascript

everyone. I got a dump question , please help.

I create a single page web-app, with marionette , require.js , and the backend is nodejs+mongodb. On the front end , I split the app as one view per file, one model per file and so on. As the app grow big, I got 50+ JavaScript files for this app. Which means, every user hit my site first time will have to down load them with 50+ http requests, this is crazy, isn't it?

So here comes the idea, I want combine all of these files into one, and make it through the google closure compiler, let user's browser relax a bit. But , all dependencies are managed by require.js , so I don't know is it possible to make this real happened.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, thank. I should read the docs more carefully , but the possibility of my idea is ok, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequireJS *ships* with support to [combine/optimize modules into a single file](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) and has support for Closure Compiler. This [optional] optimization step is one of the claimed advantages of using RequireJS and is provided tooling. It can further be paired down with [Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond).

> RequireJS has an optimization tool that does the following
>
> - Combines related scripts together into build layers and minifies them via UglifyJS (the default) or Closure Compiler (an option when using Java).
> - Optimizes CSS by inlining CSS files referenced by @import and removing comments.